# Facebook Login error "disabled Oauth client flow" but I've enabled it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

When I click on the Facebook button it show me the error "the application has disabled Oauth client flow" but I've already ENABLED Oauth client flow on facebook developers Console.

I separate it to 2 classes. But when I merge into 1 class, it works fine.

```
public class Authentication extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener{

    static protected FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;

    static FacebookLogin facebookLogin;
    static CallbackManager callbackManager;

    String TAG = "LOGIN";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.index);

        findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_signout).setOnClickListener(this);

        Button btnStudent = (Button)findViewById(R.id.student);
        final LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.button_facebook_login);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "User is signed in");

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "User is signed out");
                }
            }
        };

        btnStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginButton.performClick();
                facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin();
                facebookLogin.initFacebookLogin(loginButton, getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
    }
```

FacebookLogin.java:

```
public class FacebookLogin extends Authentication{

    protected void initFacebookLogin(LoginButton loginButton, Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Facebook Login Class" + loginButton.getText());

        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddCourse.class);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email");
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                Log.d(TAG, "Facebook success");

                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Facebook cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
        AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                Log.d(TAG, "facebook complete");
            }
        });
    }
```

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What you have done while splitting the class is absurd. `FacebookLogin` extends `Authentication` but the `Authentication` class itself has a `static` reference to `FacebookLogin`. What did you exactly want to achieve while you were splitting the class ?  The answer to your problem anyways has been answered by qbix

Answer (score 0):

You say the code stopped working when you separated it into two classes.  You separated the code by creating `FacebookLogin`, which extends `Authentication`, which is an `AppCompatActivity`.  You then added a static member to `Authentication` of type `FacebookLogin`.  That's not a good way to break out a section of code.  One problem it creates is that the system will not call back to `onActivityResult()` in `FacebookLogin`.  Instead, any activity results will be passed to the instance of activity `Authentication`.  Because it no longer has an override of `onActivityResult()`, you code is not able to process it.

Comment: It's my fault.. but i removed static of `FacebookLogin` it's still not work.